# Adding to a list of list of integers

Tags: python, list, function, addition

I have a list `x = [[2873, 5321, 5421], [2788, 5171, 5271], [2788, 5171, 5271]]`.
I want to add `y = 400`, to each of the elements in the list.
The output should be `z = [3273, 5721, 5821], 3188, 5571, 5671], [3188, 5571, 5671]]`

I tried by using

```
def add(x,y): 
addlists=[(x[i] + y) for i in range(len(x))]    
return addlists
z = add(x,y)
```

But that didn't work.

I've also tried

```
def add(x,y):
addlists = [(x[i] + [y]) for i in range(len(x))]
    return addlists
z = add(x,y)
```

But that returns `z = [[2873, 5321, 5421] + 400, [2788, 5171, 5271] + 400, [2788, 5171, 5271]+ 400]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another approach, *if* you wanted to go as far as using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html) you can use the following.

Depending on the size of your dataset, this approach might provide some **efficiency gains** over using nested loops, as `numpy` employs a method known as ['broadcasting'](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to apply a given operation to each value in the array, rather than ‘conventional looping’.

Additionally, this method scales well as it’s flexible to the shape of the lists.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

x = [[2873, 5321, 5421], [2788, 5171, 5271], [2788, 5171, 5271]]
a = np.array(x)

a + 400
```

Output:

```
array([[3273, 5721, 5821],
       [3188, 5571, 5671],
       [3188, 5571, 5671]])
```

---

#### Update:

This update addresses the following comment question:

> ... is it possible to add to only the 2 last elements in each of the list in the array ...

Yes, absolutely - use slicing. Here is a link to a [simple slicing tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp).

For example:

```
a[:,-2:] += 400
```

Output:

```
array([[2873, 5721, 5821],
       [2788, 5571, 5671],
       [2788, 5571, 5671]])
```

Explanation:

```
a[:,-2:] += 400
^ ^  ^    ^
| |  |    |
| |  |    \ Apply the addition in place.
| |  |
| |  \ Apply the addition to only the last 2 elements.
| |
| \ Apply the addition to all arrays.
|
\ Array to be sliced
```

Comment: Thanks for the a good answer, but is it possible to add to only the 2 last elements in each of the list in the array. Adding 400 to y, z, b, c in a list = [[x,y,z],[a,b,c]]? :)

Comment: @abh - Excellent, my pleasure. Have just updated the question to address your question regarding the last two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = [[2873, 5321, 5421], [2788, 5171, 5271], [2788, 5171, 5271]]

y = 400

z = [[y + each for each in eachlist] for eachlist in x]
print (z)
# result: 
[[3273, 5721, 5821], [3188, 5571, 5671], [3188, 5571, 5671]]
```